# Calling console.log from rust wasm32-wasi without the need for ssvm/ssvmup

Tags: node.js, rust, wasi

I would like to debug using messages to the console.log.

We have a rust wasm32-wasi function being called from javascript running in nodejs. We can not use ssvm/ssvmup due to other restrictions.

Is there anything we can do to see messages from our wasm code in the console?

Comment: are you using `wasm-bindgen` or something like `neon` to do the integration?

Comment: @kmdreko using wasm-bindgen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is answered in [The wasm-bindgen Guide: Using console.log](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/console-log.html):

- Method #1, binding it manually:

  ```rust
  #[wasm_bindgen]
  extern "C" {
      // Use `js_namespace` here to bind `console.log(..)` instead of just
      // `log(..)`
      #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console)]
      fn log(s: &str);

      // The `console.log` is quite polymorphic, so we can bind it with multiple
      // signatures. Note that we need to use `js_name` to ensure we always call
      // `log` in JS.
      #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console, js_name = log)]
      fn log_u32(a: u32);

      // Multiple arguments too!
      #[wasm_bindgen(js_namespace = console, js_name = log)]
      fn log_many(a: &str, b: &str);
  }

  fn bare_bones() {
      log("Hello from Rust!");
      log_u32(42);
      log_many("Logging", "many values!");
  }
  ```
- Method #2, using the [`web-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/web-sys) crate:

  ```rust
  fn using_web_sys() {
      use web_sys::console;

      console::log_1(&"Hello using web-sys".into());

      let js: JsValue = 4.into();
      console::log_2(&"Logging arbitrary values looks like".into(), &js);
  }
  ```

Another potential alternative, if you're doing a lot of logging you may want to consider using the [`log`](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate with the [`wasm-logger`](https://crates.io/crates/wasm-logger) facade:

```rust
wasm_logger::init(wasm_logger::Config::default());

// Logging
log::info!("Some info");
log::error!("Error message");
```